# How to make only one element to change onHover (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hover, onmouseover

so I'm trying to change  element color onHover by changing state, the problem is that all of the elements change, because of the state. 
How to do that only one  element would change?

link to the problem:
https://repl.it/@RokasSimkus/TediousTestyOctagons

```
class App extends Component {
    state={
    hover:false
  }
  render() {
    let onHover = () =>{
  this.setState({hover:true})
};
let onOut = () =>{
  this.setState({hover:false})
};
    return (
      <div className="App">
    <a onMouseOver={onHover} onMouseOut={onOut} style={this.state.hover? {color:'red', fontSize:'50px', cursor:'pointer'}: {color:'blue', fontSize:'50px', cursor:'pointer'}}>CHANGE LANGUAGE</a>
    <br/>
        <a onMouseOver={onHover} onMouseOut={onOut} style={this.state.hover? {color:'orange', fontSize:'50px', cursor:'pointer'}: {color:'blue', fontSize:'50px', cursor:'pointer'}}>DO SOMETHING ELSE</a>
        <br/>
                <a onMouseOver={onHover} onMouseOut={onOut} style={this.state.hover? {color:'grey', fontSize:'50px', cursor:'pointer'}: {color:'blue', fontSize:'50px', cursor:'pointer'}}>AND ELSE</a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The simple answer is to use CSS instead. The React answer is to use a separate state variable for each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of keeping track of hover as a boolean, you could keep track of a unique identifier for the hovered element and then set state.hover to that identifier on mouse over and clear it on mouse out.

```
let onHover = (id) =>{
  this.setState({hover: id})
};
let onOut = () =>{
  this.setState({hover: null})
};
```

you'd just need to update your anchors to something like this:

```
<a onMouseOver={() => onHover('CHANGE LANGUAGE'} onMouseOut={onOut} style={this.state.hover === 'CHANGE LANGUAGE' ? {color:'red', fontSize:'50px', cursor:'pointer'}: {color:'blue', fontSize:'50px', cursor:'pointer'}}>CHANGE LANGUAGE</a>
```